# simulating clicking of nodes on d3.html from dropdown/select

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drop-down-menu, force-layout

I am currently using a d3 force layout for this project. At the moment, whenever I click on a node, it shows the "details" or name of the node on a panel and shows the neighbouring nodes. I would like to achieve this when I choose from the dropdown list. Which means a user can either click on the node to get the "details" or select from the dropdown list to see the details. I was thinking to use d3.dispatch, however I have difficulties understanding it.

I've referred to answers like [putting the country on drop down list using d3 via csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780835/putting-the-country-on-drop-down-list-using-d3-via-csv-file). If I understand the answer correctly, it simulates the clicking of selection.

```
function searchNode() {

//find the node

var selectedVal = d3.event.target.value;

if (selectedVal == d.code) {
//alert(selectedVal)
showNodePanel(node);
};
}
```

You can refer to my codes at http://plnkr.co/edit/E8MfM6wfbt56i8nkf3Ym?p=preview At the moment, when I select from the dropdown, it shows an empty panel. Please can anyone guide me to the right direction with a good explanation as I'm quite new to d3. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array filter to find the selected node.

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

Here `filter` function will return -

```
[{"code":"Count","group":14,"size":"5","name":"Count","index":8,"weight":1,"x":597.5669800627312,"y":211.07030994307163,"px":597.457141196603,"py":211.1405159319426}]
```

**code:**

```
var select = d3.select("#searchNode")
    .append("select")
    .on('change.sn', searchNode)
    .on('change.smp', function () { 
      var name = this.value; //Name of the node
      var node = graph.nodes.filter(function(d){ return d.name==name; })[0]; //Find the node with the selected name.
      showNodePanel(node); //Show details
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! This works brilliantly. Care to give some explanation? From what I understand is that you have created a variable "name" to capture the value from the dropdown. Then you match the name that was captured in the dropdown with the nodes by using .filter and put it in [0] array. Based on the array filter, you call the function showNodePanel. Can you affirm this? I'm still a noob and I hope with some explanation it will help all the noobs like me out there. Thanks!

Comment: Most of your understanding is correct, except one thing. JavaScript array `filter` function returns an array always. In this code since name is unique, there would be only one array element which matches the selected name. So the size of array returned by the filter function would be 1. So we take the corresponding node with the index 0. So thus you get the required node and just need to pass that node to the `showNodePanel` function to show it's details.

Comment: Thanks for the extended effort on explaining it well. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code the d is `undefined` you need to find it from the `graph.nodes`:

```
function searchNode() {

//find the node

var selectedVal = d3.event.target.value;

if (selectedVal == d.code) {//this d is undefined you need to search this..
//alert(selectedVal)
showNodePanel(node);
};
}
```

You need to make the search node function like this:

```
function searchNode() {

    //find the node

    var selectedVal = d3.event.target.value;
    //iterate though all the nodes
    graph.nodes.every(function(n){
      if (n.code == selectedVal){
        var d = n;
        opacity =  0.05;
        //code for hiding nodes same as you have written in fade function
        //select all nodes
        d3.selectAll(".node").style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                this.setAttribute("fill-opacity", thisOpacity);
                return thisOpacity;
        });
        //select all links
        d3.selectAll(".link").style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;

        });
        return false;
      } 
      return true;
    });

}
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L8hEjfvvZ7a35K2Pte53?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake on the undefined 'd'. Very good effort with the help. However, I could see that there will be duplication of codes which the first one will be in function "fade" and function "searchnode". Is there anything that could trigger "fade" from "searchNode" function? or is there no choice but to use .dispatch? As I have difficulties understanding .dispatch. The answer that Gilsha posted does this by calling the showNodePanel instead of re-writing the similar codes. Care to explain this as I am still quite a new learner in d3.. Anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: Unfortunately I can only mark 1 answer, just to let you know that your solution does help as well. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! No issues you are able to get around it that makes the difference  :)