# D3.js - Zooming to bbox with a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, d3.js

On a map I would like to zoom on the bbox of specific countries with a dropdown menu that contains the names or ids of those countries.

I achieved to do that by clicking on the country thanks to this example : https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541.
But now I would like to do this not by clicking on the country but when I select it in a dropdown menu.

I found some answers here : [putting the country on drop down list using d3 via csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780835/putting-the-country-on-drop-down-list-using-d3-via-csv-file). But it doesn't work in my case (I think the problem is with the "jsonOutside.features.forEach(function (d)" part).

I tried that to do that but it doesn't work:

```
d3.select("#zoom").on("change", function() {    //trying to zoom on the bbox with the dropdown menu     
            var selected = this.value;          //but it doesn't work
            clicked(selected);          
});
```

I placed a console.log in this code that returns me the right value (the id of the country). I've also done that in the "clicked" function and it returns me an object.
So I think the problem is that my dropdown menu only contains countries names, not their objects that are used by the clicked function.

Here is the rest of my code :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>

        <style type="text/css">         
            #form {
                width: 20%;
                padding-top: 200px;
                margin-left: 2%;
            }

            #svg {
                display: block;
                margin-left: 30%;
                margin-top: -300px;
                border: 1px;
            }

            #map {
                border: 2px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        </div>
            <form id="form">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Zoom on</legend>
                    <div>
                        <select id="zoom">
                            <option value="01">01</option> //options containing the countries id
                            <option value="02">02</option>
                            <option value="03">03</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form> 
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var width = 600, height = 550, centered;

var path = d3.geo.path();

var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal() //focus on the topojson
    .center([2.454071, 47.279229])
    .scale(3000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

path.projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select('#map').append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var departments = svg.append("g");

function clicked(d) { //zoom on bbox function
  var x, y, k;

  if (d && centered !== d) {
    var centroid = path.centroid(d);
    x = centroid[0];
    y = centroid[1];
    k = 4;
    centered = d;
  } else {
    x = width / 2;
    y = height / 2;
    k = 1;
    centered = null;
  }

  svg.selectAll("path")
      .classed("active", centered && function(d) { return d === centered; });

  svg.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
      .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
}

d3.json('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/PierreVivet/f46c2fe235ec7d7ab2db3dbaa163cc50/raw/f2f3fb092beb94f3a0582a9a82a040fa789028c1/departements.json', function(req, data) {
    data.objects.territoire.geometries.forEach(function (d) {
        d.properties = {};
        d.properties.code = d.code;
    });

    departments.selectAll("path")
        .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.territoire).features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('id', function(d) {return "d" + d.properties.code;})
        .style("fill", "white")
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", ".5px")
        .on("click", clicked); //the function works fine by clicking on the country
});

d3.select("#zoom").on("change", function() {    //trying to zoom on the bbox with the dropdown menu     
        var selected = this.value;              //but it doesn't work
        clicked(selected);          
});
</script>
```

Do you have any ideas on how to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

I was close to it, the only problem was that I manually created the select menu with html. The point is to create and populate it directly with d3, so we can use the onclick function with the right 'd'.

The code used is as follow :

```
var select = d3.select('#map')
    .append('select')

select.selectAll("option")
    .data(topojson.feature(data, data.objects.territoire).features)
    .enter().append("option")
    .text(function(d) { return d.properties.code; })
    .on("click", function(d) { clicked(d); });
```

That was not very complex, but as I'm still new to D3 I needed to understand the syntax.

Thanks for Lars Kotthoff answers found here : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/g6PLMZbRLvs