# dropdown menu for Zooming to bbox (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to zoom in bbox depending on the option of drop down menu, I tryed the code [D3.js - Zooming to bbox with a dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835815/d3-js-zooming-to-bbox-with-a-dropdown-menu?noredirect=1&lq=1t) but it is not working,and here is a [js fiiddle of my work](https://jsfiddle.net/danaAtmeh/8gq786LL/)

```
<div id="LayerCover"style="display: inline-block;">
            </div> //this is the div where drop down menu must place 

    function mapZoomgDorow(file){

    d3.queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "Data/Updated_map.json")
    .await(menuChanged);

    }
    function menuChanged(error, jordan) {
      if (error) throw error;


        var select = d3.select('#LayerCover')
        .append('select')


        select.selectAll("option")
        .data(jordan.features)
        .enter().append("option")
        .filter(function(d) { return d.properties.Level == '1' })
        .text(function(d) { return d.properties.Name_1; console.log(d.properties.Name_1); })
        .on("click",clicked)
```

this give me the drop down menu but when I click nothing happened ,note that my function clicked is just like https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541

Comment: Is it producing errors? And is it possible to see a plunker maybe (since you can upload data files on it vs say jsFiddle)?

Comment: @AndrewReid I Updated the question with a link to jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the answer I've removed some of your code to make it more specific to the problem you are having (and thus hopefully easier to use).

When appending your features, you could append a select menu and its options:

```
// append a menu:
var select = d3.select('form')
  .append('select')
  .on('change',function() { zoom(this.value); });
var options = select.selectAll('option')
  .data(jordan.features)
  .enter()
  .append('option')
  .html(function(d) { return d.properties.name_2; })
  .attr('value',function(d,i) { return i; });
```

I'm using an old version of your jordan.json (I think you've updated it, but your fiddle wanted me to create a profile for drop box so it was easier to use the old, and I don't have your csv). You'll want to make sure that this is working before implementing the zoom functionality. Also, you'll need to place an on change event for the select menu.

Also, it might be easiest if your click (on the map) to zoom functionality and your select an option zoom functionality used the same function - if we do this they'll both need to take the same value. The increment works fine for this (unless you are modifying the number of elements in the geojson). You'll need to apply the same filter to each though - the data for the paths and the options must be the same if using the increment.

Your zoom funcion appears to work great, I've modified it slightly with an if statement: If you click or select the same feature twice, the map zooms out:

```
var last = -1;    // the last feature zoomed to
function zoom(i) {
    // if clicking on the same feature that was zoomed to last zoom out:
    if (i == last) {
        var bounds = path.bounds(jordan),
        dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
        dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
        x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
        y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
        scale = .8 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
        translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];
        last = -1;
    }
    // otherwise, zoom in:
    else {
        var bounds = path.bounds(jordan.features[i]),
            dx = bounds[1][0] - bounds[0][0],
            dy = bounds[1][1] - bounds[0][1],
            x = (bounds[0][0] + bounds[1][0]) / 2,
            y = (bounds[0][1] + bounds[1][1]) / 2,
            scale = .8 / Math.max(dx / width, dy / height),
            translate = [width / 2 - scale * x, height / 2 - scale * y];

        last = i;
    }
    g.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / scale + "px")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + scale + ")");
}
```

I've put together a [block here](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/fae9fc04e0fe9cd410b2c854b880a19e).

Comment: This  work really good also in the updated json file I got ..thank you very much